# Java - Send Email using Default Email Provider

Tags: java

I have written a Java Code so that if a button is pressed the default email provider would open up automatically to be able to send an email. is there a possibility that i can attach a file to the email automatically and set a subject for the emails?

this is the code so far:

```
        if(role.getValue().equals("1")) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=see attachment&attachment="PVS_XML.xml""));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
        }
```

the code above is for some reason not working: its underlining the whole of mailto method saying : Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements.

Any ideas why ?

Comment: what is the specific problem/question?

Comment: well, the best possible method to enable the functionality to click on a button, then outlook should start up with a specific file attachment, where then the user will be able to enter the recipient subject and message? this should be supportive with Java and Wicket.

Comment: You can use mailto with link but it won't add attachment and will run the default mail program as mentioned. You may want to create/send the email completely within the application and expect a recipeint address along with a send button in your wicket application

Comment: is there a possibility that I can attach a subject and file to the email automatically. please see amended code above.

Answer (score 2):

Add a "mailto:username@domain.com" link. This should trigger your browser to startup the standard mail programm.

This has nothing to do with Wicket. It is standard browser behavior.

Comment: with which library should i use it?

Comment: Shall i just write a method where the link is triggered as soon the button is pressed? And that in the Java Coding?

Comment: There is no library needed: <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">blabla</a>

Comment: well i need to write it in Java though. i just tried this:    if(role.getValue().equals("1")) {
    //E-Mail the PDF File as an Attachment to User.
     Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("mailto:username@domain.com"));  
   }

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. Is there a way, that I can set the subject of the message and also attach a document to it automatically from the java code?

Answer (score 2):

```
'mailto:email@email.com?subject=Software&body=see attachment&attachment="C:/abc/def/qwertyp.zip"'
```

Try above it should work

EDIT 1:

Not sure if it will work from Desktop but as a link from a web page

From java as a string:

```
"'mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=see attachment&attachment=\"PVS_XML.xml\"";
```

EDIT 2:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        String message = "mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=seeAttachment&attachment=c:/Update8.txt";
        URI uri = URI.create(message);
        desktop.mail(uri);
```

Also found out that attachment part is not implemented in Outlook so it doesn't support attachments using mailto. It depends on the mail client to implement parsing the attachment parameter.

Comment: there seems to be some syntax error in there:             Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI('mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=see attachment&attachment="C:/abc/def/qwertyp.zip"'));

Comment: You will need to escape the / chars if you are using it in java

Comment: its underling the first speechmark right at the beginning before mailto and its saying Invalid character constant

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI('mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=see attachment&attachment="PVS_XML.xml"'));

Comment: You need to use java rules if you are using from java. Use double quotation for strings

Comment: i dont think i can have to double quotations, right? like this ->          Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=see attachment&attachment="PVS_XML.xml""));


this is the error message for that (its underlining the whole mailto method) : Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements

Comment: it gives me an error message: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 'mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=see attachment&attachment="PVS_XML.xml"

Comment: It compiles and works, but the document is not getting attached though.

Comment: Seems like outlook does not support attachment parameter within mailto URIs

Comment: If an attachment doesnt work, is it possible to gather specific data from input fields in my java program and put this into the body of the email? if so, could you please advise what i need to do?

Comment: You can send the email yourself within your application instead of using the email client. @See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=send+email+from+java

Answer (score 0):

`Desktop` won't work because it runs on the server, not on the client. It may open an Outlook window in your server, though :)

You should yse an `mailto:` link, as others said. The user will have to attach the file manually, though. The browser forces this due security concerns.

Comment: I just need the machine to start up outlook and thats fine. it doesnt need to be an email application within java. outlook is more than fine. but the attachment is a must for me. what way is there for me to attach a file to the email automatically?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that, unless you use some very insecure methods (from the user standpoint), like signed applets.